# How to change label of a second viewController since first viewController?

Tags: storyboard, swift

I have two viewControllers in my Swift storyboard and if I try change a text label of my second view controller since my first viewController but I can't.. I get a EXC_Breakpoint.

I'm trying with segue function but there are the same problem.. There is the same problem to change labels, textFields, imageView...

How can I make this?

Thanks!

Edit. my code:

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var label1 : UILabel

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "modal") {
        var vista = (segue.destinationViewController.visibleViewController as View2)
        vista.label2.text = "i am a new value"
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
...
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass Values through segues.

For Example here: Put some Value From a MainView to a ModalView

```
// 1. create Instance of Window and pass a certain value

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(segue.identifier == "modal") {

        var ModalWindow = (segue.destinationViewController.visibleViewController as ModalTableViewController)
        ModalWindow.value = "i am a new value"
    }
}

// in your other Viewcontroller you can use this variable  

class ModalTableViewController: {

    var value:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

    // No you can use your Value to set a Textfield value for example.

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get error EXC_Breakpoint in line if(segue.identifier == "modal") what could be this?

Comment: You probably have no identifier which is called "modal" - click (if you are using Interface Builder) on the Connection Badge between your Views and set the name of the segue to "modal".

Comment: Provide some Code, otherwise its hard to help. Or check one of the Swift Tutorial Videos on youtube (They explain how do use multiple Windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=war0gHL26ns)

Comment: I guess its easier to check out the Tutorial Video. Why you connect your Windows in Both directions? Just close your Second View with: self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) - And Use @IBOutlet var label1 : UILabel! (with !) And you need to Perform a Segue on button Click with: performSegueWithIdentifier("modal", sender: self)

Comment: I change this but get the same error, and in video i don't know how to  pass data

Comment: Ok - so now your new Window gets opened as expected? You can pass data if you check my example. Just set up the new View Controller with your value.

Comment: I try this again in empty project and get the same error EXC_Breakpoint in line if(segue.identifier == "modal") I don't know

Comment: Upload your Project somewhere.

Comment: Ok there a lot of mistakes in your Code: Here is a example with a NavigationController -> http://www.file-upload.net/download-9297603/testswitchwindows.zip.html